# How can I get specific values from NDSolve (coupled ODEs)?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

The codes are as follows

```
Module[{α = 1, β = 0.76, γ = 5/3, p, M, pre = 0.2}, 
  {s = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][p][r] == 
       -((α*p[r]^(1/γ)*M[r])/r^2), 
      Derivative[1][M][r] == β*r^2*p[r]^(1/γ), 
      p[0.2] == 10^(-4), M[0.2] == 0}, {p[r], M[r]}, 
     {r, pre, 20}], Plot[Evaluate[p[r] /. s], 
    {r, pre, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"r(KM)", 
      "p/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϵ\), \(0\)]\)"}], 
   Plot[Evaluate[M[r] /. s], {r, pre, 20}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> 
     {"r(KM)", "M/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(0\)]\)"}], 
   M[16.7] /. s}]
```

but the output gives `M[16.7]` instead of a specific value of the function.

Comment: To be more specific, change `{p[r], M[r]}` to `{p, M}`.

Comment: In the solution `s` you solved for `M[r]` so the last part of the code should be `M[r] /. s /. r -> 16.7`

Comment: it is better to use `{p, M}` in `NDSolve` than `{p[r], M[r]}`